# Subsetting slot from a list of data.frames

Tags: r

I would like to extract the line: "miRFamily" from the following list resulting from an annotation procedure:

> ```
> List of 3    
>  $ 87   :Formal class 'targetscanTarget' [package "targetscan.Hs.eg.db"] with 7 slots     
>  .. ..@ miRFamily: chr [1:18] "miR-218/218a" "miR-218/218a" "miR-218/218a" "miR-384/384-3p"    
>  .. ..@ UTRstart : int [1:18] 331 331 331 318 318 318 224 224 224 157 ...    
>  .. ..@ UTRend   : int [1:18] 338 338 338 324 324 324 230 230 230 163 ...     
>  .. ..@ MSAstart : int [1:18] 701 701 701 688 688 688 535 535 535 363 ...     
>  .. ..@ MSAend   : int [1:18] 708 708 708 694 694 694 541 541 541 369 ...     
>  .. ..@ Seedmatch: chr [1:18] "8mer" "8mer" "8mer" "7mer-1a" ...     
>  .. ..@ PCT      : chr [1:18] "0.77" "0.77" "0.77" "NULL" ...      
> $ 6876 :Formal class 'targetscanTarget' [package "targetscan.Hs.eg.db"] with 7 slots
>  .. ..@ miRFamily: chr [1:6] "miR-485-5p/1698/1703/1962" "miR-485-5p/1698/1703/1962"            "miR-539/539-5p" "miR-539/539-5p" ...      
>  .. ..@ UTRstart : int [1:6] 170 170 427 427 149 149         
>  .. ..@ UTRend   : int [1:6] 177 177 433 433 155 155             
>  .. ..@ MSAstart : int [1:6] 183 183 605 605 157 157            
>  .. ..@ MSAend   : int [1:6] 199 199 630 630 163 163               
>  .. ..@ Seedmatch: chr [1:6] "8mer" "8mer" "7mer-1a" "7mer-1a" ...                
>  .. ..@ PCT      : chr [1:6] "NULL" "NULL" "NULL" "NULL" ...              
> $ 10398:Formal class 'targetscanTarget' [package "targetscan.Hs.eg.db"] with 7 slots                
>  .. ..@ miRFamily: chr [1:2] "miR-491-5p" "miR-491-5p"                
>  .. ..@ UTRstart : int [1:2] 391 391                                 
>  .. ..@ UTRend   : int [1:2] 398 398                 
>  .. ..@ MSAstart : int [1:2] 577 577                   
>  .. ..@ MSAend   : int [1:2] 598 598                   
>  .. ..@ Seedmatch: chr [1:2] "8mer" "8mer"                    
>   .. ..@ PCT      : chr [1:2] "NULL" "NULL"
> ```

Can anyone help me please?

> ```
> dput(miRNA_annotation)
>   structure(list(`87` = <S4 object of class structure("targetscanTarget", package =     "targetscan.Hs.eg.db")>, 
>  `6876` = <S4 object of class structure("targetscanTarget", package = "targetscan.Hs.eg.db")>, 
> `10398` = <S4 object of class structure("targetscanTarget", package = "targetscan.Hs.eg.db")>), .Names = c("87", 
> "6876", "10398"))
> ```

Best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
get_miRFamily <- function(my_list){return(my_list@miRFamily)}
lapply(my_list, get_miRFamily)
```

A test case on lists:

```
get_miRFamily_test <- function(my_list){return(my_list$miRFamily)}
list1 <- list(miRFamily = 5, y = 6)
list2 <- list(miRFamily = 7, z  = 'ad')
y <- list('5' = list1, '80' = list2)
lapply(y, get_miRFamily_test)
```

Should produce:

```
$`5`
[1] 5

$`80`
[1] 7
```

Just note that you must use @ and not $ for your data. That is also the difference between the get_miRFamily and get_miRFamily_test functions.